# Palantir Foundry - Data Connection to copy PDF files from Compass Folder to external source?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

In Palantir Foundry -
Is there a data connector that will export files (PDFs) from the Compass folder system to an external source like SharePoint or a shared network drive? Every connection type I am familiar with relies on a [data export task that exports files from a dataset filesystem](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/filesystems-and-blob-stores/sharepoint-online/index.html#export-data-to-sharepoint-online).

We need to export PDFs from a regular Foundry folder to some external source. We're flexible on the destination (SharePoint, shared drive, ?) - we have hundreds of PDFs to download and unfortunately Foundry does not seem to allow any kind of mass downloading from the UI.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you're storing 'many' pdfs, you'll want to put them inside a dataset or similar, this enables you to handle them in bulk, both for export and in pipelines, ontology & applications.

I would re-upload the PDFs to a dataset without a schema, then use the data connection export functionality.

If you could please provide some more details about how the PDFs got there, I might be able to suggest an easier way to get them into a dataset?

Comment: hello, thank you for this answer! Moving them to a dataset would be preferred so was our backup plan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77312750/palantir-foundry-how-to-load-pdf-files-from-compass-folder-into-code-repositor
But, still would be interesting to know if Palantir has the capability to export from Compass. There are hundreds of files in this Compass folder structure with seemingly no 'simple' way to move them out.

Comment: Adding more context that in our case we don't have a central location with all the files that we can just re-upload. They are files that have been uploaded over time by individual external users. Without the programmatic copy from Compass to a dataset filesystem linked in my first comment, someone would have to download each file 1 by 1 through the UI, which seems impractical.

Comment: @tessa yep, as a one off, the approach you linked to is good.  Alternatively, if you have logic flows installed, you could use that: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/compass-file-lister/index.html#compass-file-lister

Comment: Thanks, I'll just assume that at the time of these comments there is no Foundry data connector for exporting compass files and the details outlined here are current best practices. Our internal product support has not found a data connection.